# Arzelà-Ascoli for manifolds

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request

On the German Wikipedia one can read the following about the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem:

> The theorem of Arzelà-Ascoli can be generalised to families of
>   equicontinuous maps with values in a compact manifold.

Unfortunately, no reference is given. Does anybody has a reference for this statement?

Comment: The version of Ascoli's theorem in Munkres' topology book (Section 7-6) is for continuous mappings from a locally compact Hausdorff space to a metric space. Is that not sufficient for your needs?

Comment: @KCd Thank you. Yes, that seems promising! The problem is now showing that a family of loops is equicontinuous under a Riemannian distance function...but that is another story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every compact Riemannian manifold carries a Riemannian metric. Given such a metric, you can embed it isometrically into $\mathbb{R}^N$ for sufficiently large $N$ by Nash's embedding theorem and apply Arzelà-Ascoli to each of the component functions. Of course, this is a huge overkill.

General versions of the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem that cover the case you mention can be found in most introductory books on general topology, see e.g. Theorem 8.2.10 in Engelking, *General Topology*.